# Setting Common labels and background color common for all the charts in ChartJs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Hi guys i am using [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) for creating pie charts,it is pretty good.In my project i have to create many pie charts, all the charts will have the same labels and background color.In the code given below i am giving the backgroundColor and label while creating the pie charts individually.Is there any way to make label and background color common for all the charts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> ChartJS tutorial </title>
 <style type="text/css">
        #pie-charts-wrapper{
         width:1000px;
         margin-left:auto;
         margin-right:auto;
        }
        .pie-chart-wrapper{
         width:500px;
         height:300px;
         box-sizing:border-box;
         float:left;
         padding:20px;
        }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="pie-charts-wrapper">
       <div class="pie-chart-wrapper">
          <canvas id="pieChart1" width="500px" height="300" ></canvas>
       </div>
       <div class="pie-chart-wrapper">
          <canvas id="pieChart2" width="500px" height="300" ></canvas>
       </div>
    </div>       

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ctx1 = document.getElementById("pieChart1");
        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("pieChart2");

  var data1 = {
      labels: ['Signed','Not Signed'],
      datasets: [{
       backgroundColor:['#1abc9c','#34495e'],
        data: [10, 25],
      }],
  };

  var data2 = {
      labels: ['Signed','Not Signed'],
      datasets: [{
       backgroundColor:['#1abc9c','#34495e'],
        data: [15, 2]
      }],
  };

  var myPieChart1 = new Chart(ctx1,{
      type: 'pie',
      data: data1
  });

  var myPieChart2 = new Chart(ctx2,{
      type: 'pie',
      data: data2
  });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speaking technically then **yes**, there is a way. Though it­*'s* not recommended, as that­*'s* not how ChartJS meant to work, therefore no built-in functionality either.

To accomplish this you would rather go for kind of a hacky solution, which is to use a plugin, like the following :

```
Chart.plugins.register({
   beforeInit: function(chart) {
      chart.data.labels = ['Signed', 'Not Signed'];
      chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = ['#1abc9c', '#34495e'];
   }
});
```

<sup>* add this at the beginning of your script</sup>

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
   beforeInit: function(chart) {
      chart.data.labels = ['Signed', 'Not Signed'];
      chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = ['#1abc9c', '#34495e'];
   }
});

var ctx1 = document.getElementById("pieChart1");
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("pieChart2");

var data1 = {
   datasets: [{
      data: [10, 25],
   }]
};

var data2 = {
   datasets: [{
      data: [15, 2]
   }]
};

var myPieChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
   type: 'pie',
   data: data1
});

var myPieChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
   type: 'pie',
   data: data2
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="pieChart1" width="500px" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="pieChart2" width="500px" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: one small query, it is also affecting other charts like bar chart which i am creating for another purpose.is there a way the above work for only pie charts

Comment: Yes, add `if (chart.config.type !== 'pie') return;` at the beginning of `beforeInit` function.

Comment: You are a genius :)